# AMQP Rabbitmq Nodejs - Additional publisher created each time when subscriber goes down

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Currenty i have following situation:

---

publisher.js:

```
var queue_connection = new amqp.createConnection( { host: config.rabbitmq.host, port: config.rabbitmq.port }  );

queue_connection.on( 'ready', function () {

    var exchange = queue_connection.exchange( 'http_worker', { type: 'topic' } );
        exchange.on( 'open', function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                exchange.publish( 'AZ', 'This is test message' );
                logger.info( 'AZ message pushed' );
            }, 1000);
    })
});
```

---

subscriber.js:

```
var connection = amqp.createConnection({ host: config.rabbitmq.host, port: config.rabbitmq.port });

connection.on( 'ready', function () {

    connection.queue( 'AZ', function ( q ) {

        q.bind( 'http_worker', 'AZ' );

        q.subscribe(function ( message ) {
            console.log(unescape( message.data ))
        });
    });

});
```

---

Example above works just fine. When i start publisher.js and subscriber.js, subscriber is going to receive messages without any kind of issues.
But if i close subscriber, and start it again (without closing and starting publisher.js), subscriber is going to start receiving 3 same messages at once.

- I suppose that this is happening because of 3 callbacks in publisher.js, but I dont understand why those callbacks are called each time when subscriber goes down
- How can i prevent this from happening? Is there any kind of options for rabbitmq/amqp to force publisher to wait for the subscriber to reconnect again.
- Additionally is it possible to achieve this without losing messages from the queue, queued while subscriber was down?
- Is there a difference when you are starting subscriber first and then publisher (and vice versa). How this works, who needs to create a queue, subscriber or publisher?

---

**EDITED:**

Based on:

> The default for both queues and exchanges is to automatically delete them when there are no consumers (for queues) or queues (for exchanges) bound to them, which is happening in your situation.

adding  "autoDelete: false" resolves an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for both queues and exchanges is to automatically delete them when there are no consumers (for queues) or queues (for exchanges) bound to them, which is happening in your situation.

You can see that when you add an error event handler:

```
queue_connection.on('error', console.log);
```

When that happens, the connection is closed by RabbitMQ, the `amqp` driver reconnects, it re-emits the `ready` event, and you re-create the exchange.

However, the previous exchange instance (from the first connection) is still running and keeps on publishing messages as well (which apparently is valid, although I suspect that the message get dropped).

So after the first reconnect you have *two* publishers sending messages. Disconnect a subscriber, get the error, reconnect, and a third publisher is started. Etc.

You probably need to track the state of the connection so make sure that you clean up any exchange or queue instances when the connection is reset.

Comment: Indeed. Seems that adding "autoDelete: false" as one of the exchange options resolve this issue.